# change the Rule parameters in ODM Rule Server at runtime?

Tags: parameters, runtime, business-rules, odm

I want to know this is possible to change the Rule parameters in ODM Rule Execution Server in runtime?
For example:
" if the age of customer is more than 15 "
Change to
" if the age of customer is more than 20 ".

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ODM Rule Execution server, as the name states, is used as a server to execute rulesets. Rule set contains action rules and decision tables in a flow to be executed. If a parameter or value or threshold of a condition needs to be changed, it has to be modified in Decision Center and deploy it to Rule Execution Server.

That is how Rule Execution Server and Decision Center communicate.